# How to add checkbox to eclipse "Delete resources" window?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to add a checkbox to "Delete resources window" which appears when the user wants to delete a certain project from the workspace.

That checkbox should be placed below "Delete project contents on disk(this cannot be undone)" .

I will like to do this with a plugin.

How can I do this and also to add some code to the "OK" button of the window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the first page of this dialog (`org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2`)

You can use the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants` extension point to write a [Delete Participant](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ltk_core_refactoring_deleteParticipants.html) which takes part in the delete and can veto the delete if required. The delete participants are shown on the 'Preview' page of the delete dialog.

Comment: And how can I make this delete participant visible in the preview window ?

Comment: The participant is shown if it creates a `Change` object.